# How to refresh links to files on the Cloud?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet and although I update all the links when I open the spreadsheet, the links don't update.

The only solution I found is a VBA macro that replaces "`=`" with "`=`". This works, but takes ages to update. All the cells are linked to 100 individual files on the Cloud.

Is there a better way?

```vb
Sub update()
    Windows("Company Database.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Tearsheet").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
      ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I wonder if a reduction in workload would make a difference. Try, `Sheets("Tearsheet").UsedRange.Cells.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
      ReplaceFormat:=False`

Comment: What's the code you use for updating links on open? How is that code called? Does the code actually run?

Comment: How about `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Calculate
End Sub`
in ThisWorkbook Object?

Comment: Tell me, if you use DATA>>REFRESH ALL will update the links???

Comment: No unfortunately, DATA>>Refresh all doesn't do the trick.  I don't know if its something to do with the links to the OneDrive files, or something else, but the only thing that seems to  work is the very blunt tool of replace = with =.  I'll try the other suggestions too..  Thanks all!!

Answer (score 0):

May be this works

```
Sub update()
    ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources, Type:=xlExcelLinks
End Sub
```

or maybe this:

```
  Sub update()
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
  End Sub
```